# Handle IoC configuration with shared dependencies between projects

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, configuration, inversion-of-control

I've a root project (`root`), some modules (`A`, `B`), and these modules have some external dependencies (`Z`). I'm using an IoC container.

I'm using C# here, but is a generic pattern question. Let say that my container is `services`, and I can initialize IoC configuration with use of extension methods. So in `root` project I'm writing:

```
services.AddModuleA();
services.AddModuleB();
```

On module `A` I've this method:

```
public static void AddModuleA(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Init module internal services.
    //services.AddScoped<IA1Service, A1Service>();
    //...

    // Init module external dependencies.
    services.AddDependencyZ();
}
```

On module `B` I've a similar method:

```
public static void AddModuleB(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Init module internal services.
    //...

    // Init module external dependencies.
    services.AddDependencyZ();
}
```

Obviously `Z` dependency was already been added, so this tells me that I should not configure it inside a module extension method, and I should rather declare its configuration in `root` project:

```
services.AddModuleA();
services.AddModuleB();
services.AddDependencyZ();
```

But doesn't this break the Least Knowledge principle? Importing and configuring a module `A` (or `B`) will bring to a cascade explicit declaration of all dependency configurations.

And related question, is declaring the extension methods `AddModuleA()` and `AddModuleB()` a bad pattern at all? Could be a better idea to configure directly on `root` only services that I will use?
And in this case (a bit extreme), what about config of internal use only class?

Comment: Consider using a `TryAddDependencyZ()` that checks first that it has not already been added before trying to add it.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that those extension methods are defined in your application's [Composition Root](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot), why don't you just remove the call to `AddDependencyZ` from within `AddModuleA` and `AddModuleB`?

```
public static void AddModuleA(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Init module internal services.
    //services.AddScoped<IA1Service, A1Service>();
    //...
}

public static void AddModuleB(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Init module internal services.
    //...
}
```

You would then, as you write, configure the container in the Composition Root (this is the *Register* phase in the [RRR pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasepattern)):

```
services.AddModuleA();
services.AddModuleB();
services.AddDependencyZ();
```

Does this break the Least Knowledge principle? Yes, it does, but that's one of the many drawbacks of using a DI Container.

I recommend [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di) instead of using a DI Container. That would make the problem disappear because all the code in the OP would be redundant.

Comment: Is it better for a module to export a callback function that register it’s dependencies or for a single file that imports the classes of each module and do all the dependency registering for all the modules ?

Comment: @calveeen The latter. That's the point of the Composition Root. If you do the former, you couple the module to a particular DI framework. Also, different application contexts may require different configurations (lifetimes, etc.). The module can't predict how it will be used, so a callback may not offer sufficient reusability.

Comment: I see, OPs method of registering dependencies seem to be that of callback based. The composition root approach would have the `addModuleA` and `addModuleB` methods inside the composition root package rather than in `moduleA` and `moduleB` ?

Comment: @calveeen, yes.